# How to make a numbered list in bookdown that auto numbers

Tags: r, bookdown

I'm converting some Sweave files to rmarkdown/bookdown.  I have numbered lists.  In latex these are

```
\begin{itemize}
\item one
\item two
\end{itemize}
```

If I just had 2 items, I'd write

```
1. one
2. two
```

using standard rmarkdown.  But my lists are 20-30 items and I move things around when editing.  The latter is the problem. I'll have to renumber everything when I delete or add one \item.

Answer (score 0):

In standard markdown, lists **are** autonumbered no matter what number is at the start of the list. For example, below is a numbered list where the numbers are not in order - the list items show in text the numbers that start the list item, but when converted to HTML ordered numbers are used. (Click *edit* to view the markdown source if you'd like to verify.)

1. one
2. one
3. one
4. seven
5. nineteen

So, it doesn't matter what numbers you use or whether they are in order. You can start every item with `1.` if you would like.

Comment: Thanks!  It didn't occur to me to try that.  What I really want is the numbers with the chapter #, so 1.1, 1.2,...  I can see that that is possible with the theorem environment, but I can't see the bookdown definition of that environment.  My attempts using latex syntax have failed as have my attempts to find the bookdown definitions of theorem, lemma, environments.

Comment: That sounds like a different question. I'd suggest opening a new question to ask that. It also seems like you should just be able to use sections or subsections for that, but I'm not sure...